# command to check whether a file is executable for a given user on AIX 7.1

Tags: aix

How to check whether a user has been assigned privilege to execute certain files(what command can be used for checking it). for example: if a user wants to check the lssec controls,he/she should have permission of the /usr/bin/lssec file.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid it is not clear what it is you are asking here. Perhaps you could edit your question to make that clear and also indicate what action you have taken to find the answer yourself? Eg have you looked at the manuals or online resources?

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `su - username -c 'test -x /usr/bin/lssec'`

Comment: Why did you use the `db2` tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you are `root` user, you can try this:

```
User=popeye
Prog=/usr/bin/lssec
if su - "$User" -c "test -x $Prog"; then
    echo "'$User' has execute-right on '$Prog'"
fi
```